# Excel: How to copy/paste Conditional Formatting, as if the condition were a "value"?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Just like Excel allows you to *Copy & Paste* cells as a `Value` (ignoring formatting), how can I do the opposite?

In this example, I want to retain the yellow Conditional Formats, even after **I delete Column R**. So in a way retain the condition as a "value" inside the cells in Column Q.

[image]

Currently I have to **hide** Column R so the conditional formatting is retained. If I remove the column entirely, I've then lost the formatting because it's based on a formula.

i.e.

```
=IF(R2="*",true,false)
```

I wish Excel had a Copy/Paste **Colours**.

Comment: What’s wrong with paste special formats? Maybe I’m missing something. It already exists.

Comment: @BradDixon try it. LOL.. they still disappear, after the referencing column has been deleted.

Comment: oh ok I get you now.

Comment: Yeah, conditional formatting will do that to you but regular formatting will work. I reckon we could get that solved for you using VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Brad Dixon* said, VBA was the only solution...

```
Public Sub HighlightColumn()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim wsCell As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    'loop through each row
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_1")  'my data is inside a table
    For Each rw In tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
        Set wsCell = rw.Cells(1, 17)
        If rw.Cells(1, 18) = "*" Then
            With wsCell
                .Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End With
        End If
    Next rw

    'the golden moment!
    tbl.Range(, 18).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: `rw.Cells(1, 17).Interior.Color = rw.Cells(1, 17).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` would apply the CF fill color as a regular fill which would remain after the CF fill was no longer applied.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry I don't get your point, as the code above worked, regardless of which of the two options you've mentioned were applied.

Comment: I wasn't saying your code is wrong, just giving you another option which would avoid needing to hard-code the fill color...